# Can I afford to buy a used car?

Tags: united-states, car

I will be 18 in 2 weeks and I need a new car before I start college (in about 6 months). I make around $1200 a month right now and I have $1050 saved. After I start college I will have to get a new job because I’m moving out of state. Can I afford to do payments at a buy here pay here car lot (~$10,000 + full coverage insurance) or should I save up to buy one that is about $7,000.

Comment: Unfortunately there is ABSOLUTELY NO CHANCE you can afford a car.  I am sorry to say it.  Truly set this idea aside.

Comment: If by payments you mean, get a LOAN - that's a "LOL", forget it.  It's inconceivable you would get a loan.  (Note, just one issue, that would force you to have comprehensive insurance on the vehicle, which is just risible/dadaist.)

Comment: I don't see a need for you to spend $7 - $10K on a car. As Fattie notes in his answer, shoot for $3 - $4K. We also have no idea what your other expenses are. You make $1,200/mo now, but how much are you spending on other stuff? How much are you going to have to spend once you get to college? If you won't have a job when you get there, you can't assume $1,200/mo of income anymore. We really need more data.

Comment: An acquaintance in the US who's worth would be high 8 figures recently bought a car.  i don't have the actual link but exactly like this https://www.cars.com/vehicledetail/detail/832103328/overview/ So it is a literally as-if-from-the-factory Lincoln Town Car (which is simply the most comfortable, smoothest and best large luxury car ever made), perhaps 40,000 miles, it was $8,000 plus appox $2,000 for one of thse "CarMax style" "new car warranties on a used car" (utterly everything covered to 100,000 miles),. So $10k total for a literally-as-new copy of the arguably best vehicle in existence,

Comment: , with literally a better than any major manufacturer new car warranty (utterly everything covered) through 100k.  his comment was "I am such a fool for wasting so much money on cars, think what I could have turned that money in to in a few years"

Comment: Hi Samra, please don't finance ANY car from a "buy here, pay here" lot. If you wish to buy from them, fine. Just don't owe them any money, it is very expensive and can go bad in so many ways.

Comment: @Fattie: "arguably best vehicle in existence"?  Surely you're joking?  Especially for a college student.  But your general point is good: I drive a Mazda Miata that I paid less than $3K for.  Other student-appropriate vehicles such as a Honda Fit & Nissan Cube can be had for unde $5K.

Comment: @jamesqf All things considered, included the upfront cost and maintenance, I think it's a strong contender. They're comfortable, notoriously reliable, very easy to work on, and can be had for less than 5 grand any day of the week in southeast US. I think some American cars are a little overlooked on the used market.

Comment: Are you sure you need a car? I lived on-campus for years without a car. Are you living with your parents? If not, can you rent closer to the college and walk or use public transportation?

Comment: @jamesqf - i actually just meant they are the smoothest luxury barge.  Of course, this is not a car debate site and it's deside the point! unrelatedly, as Spooky mentions, they are incredibly cheap to maintain (surprisingly, even though physically large). the suggestions you make are perfect for a student. to be crystal clear **the OP here shoudl not, and any way can not, buy a car. No car.**

Comment: I seriously think the mention in the question of using a buy-here-pay-here car yard should perhaps be edited out.  It is too outlandish to have in print.

Comment: @jamesqf fattie was not saying that a college student should buy that car.  The purpose was to say that even someone who can afford to buy the newest expensive car bought an old used car.

Comment: @Fattie I bet it's not "physically large" compared to Town Cars of the 1970s... :)

Comment: @RonJohn: As I said, I completely agree with the idea of buying older used cars.  It's what I do myself, even though I could easily afford new.  I was just flabbergasted by the idea of a Lincoln Town Car as the "best vehicle in existence".

Comment: @RonJohn - really !  You know, I myself (in the US) had one of the "current" (now no longer produced) Lincoln Town Cars.  (as it in the "cars.com" photo above)  (my one cost maybe $5000 - ran as new.)  It was magnificent.  I have never been in one of the "old-school" ones!  R.I.P., beloved Town Car!  Cried when I sold it!  As SPOOKY mentions they are just ridiculously reliable, and would be literally one of the cheapest cars to maintain, parts cost nothing, fix anything with a pair of pliers. Anyway I dont mean to turn it in to a car chat, sorry guys !!!!

Answer (score 3):

Remember **auto insurance**, fuel and maintenance, plus whatever you spend on food and enjoyment: go for a $5-6000 car, and bank the rest for *unforeseen events* and the time it takes to get a job.

- Money in the bank gives you options -- freedom to choose -- you don't have when there's no money in the bank.
- Make a budget.  It's grammar school math, and a simple equation: what goes out must equal what goes in.

In this case, "what goes out" includes saving for *deferred spending*:

1. the oil's going to need changing,
2. the tires will need replacing,
3. the state makes you re-register the car,
4. it's a used car, so things might break,
5. if you're in an accident, you'll need money for a different car.

As a parent and Old Geezer: IMO, embrace the notion of "poor college student".  When you graduate, you'll have more money and less debt when you graduate.

Comment: Please highlight/boldface **insurance**. I do not have an 18-year-old in my household so I have no firsthand experience, but a little Googling gives me ballpark $400-600 per month to insure an 18yo driver in the U.S. in 2020.

Comment: @shoover that was the cost for my two kids.  Definitely nothing to sneeze at.

Comment: Indeed, R.John has hit the nail on the head: INSURANCE.  Why oh why does everyone forget this when it is often the biggest cost ?!?!?!!

Comment: An example about the value of cash: I was looking for a laptop for a young relative. One was offered for £479 cash, or £21.20 monthly for 36 months. Now multiply £21.20 x 36.  (I was  actually a bit shocked).

Comment: @gnasher729 that works out to be 16.8% APR.

Comment: @shoover What the heck are kids driving nowadays? 10-15 years ago I was driving a 1992 Camry and paid $240 every 6 months on my parent's insurance. I truly fear how expensive it's going to be in 16 years when my kids start driving...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Where I live, their parents put them in Chevy Suburbans and GMC Tahoes because the thinking is that if/when they get in a wreck, their parents want them to survive. Of course that means that whatever they hit gets the worse end of the deal. It's an arms race.

Comment: @shoover have more kids, and put them in Yugos!!!

Comment: @shoover Sounds like a big game of cat and mouse. SUV drivers are more likely to be in an accident in the first place but if that accident involves a sedan then the SUV is more likely to survive but rollovers kill SUV drivers more often. I guess bigger is better when defensive driving cannot be instilled but I digress...

Answer (score 3):

(You absolutely cannot get a car currently - just **totally forget that idea**.)

Your plan would be:

1. Achieve $12,000 in solid savings
2. Achieve separately, $1,000 saved in a distinct account for emergencies.
3. If you own a car (a starter car), you need to **set $50 a week aside** automatically as a "sinking fund" to pay for everything (tires, inevitable repairs, etc). You need a separate account for this. It must be paid $50 a week automatically.  (Obviously old people with more expensive cars and many cars, set aside much more than that per week automatically in such a sinking fund.) You must setup the $50/week automatic transfer at your bank and...
4. You must **let the sinking fund run for 10 weeks**, for two critical reasons. (A) load it up and (B) prepare for the cost of the sinking fund every week, get used to it.

Once you have achieved 1, 2, 3 and 4, purchase a fine car.  For $3500 you can easily buy a car that runs as if new from the factory and has all comforts.

(I recently had to buy a "spare car" and we found an absolutely incredible one for $5,000.  For a starter car, $3,500 is in the "magnificent" realm, it would be like me buying a Veyron.)

You MUST achieve 1, 2, 3 and 4 before purchase.

NOTE: obviously, once you have done 1, 2, 3, 4, only buy a car if you *truly and profoundly* need one.  If there's a way to do without, do without.